# Finding items in listview by typing first letter WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview which binds customer informations from database. There are 15 columns which are binded in that listview. One of that column is Customer Name.

I want to be focused them when I type their  name's initial character from the keyboard. Have you any idea to make this ?

This is my listview's XAML code

```
<ListView x:Name="datalist" ButtonBase.Click="datalist_Click" ContextMenuOpening="datalist_ContextMenuOpening" MouseDoubleClick="datalist_MouseDoubleClick" SelectionChanged="datalist_SelectionChanged"
MouseUp="datalist_MouseUp" PreviewMouseUp="datalist_PreviewMouseUp" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to operate only on `Model/ModelView` and not on `UI` directly (as much as it possible).

For example, define in `ModelView` a property

```
public bool Focused{
  get ..   
  set...  //OnPropertyChanged
}
```

nd bind it to the UI elements corresponding property. 
After this the only thing you need to do is t simply

- find an element in binded data (`ModelView` objects)
- set it's `Focused` property to `true`

Comment: @lsi: your UI element (list view row in this case) should have kind of *Focused* or *Selected* property. Bind it to corresponding property in your ModelView.

Comment: @lsi: can have look in example provided in the asnwer on this question [WPF ListView Programmatically Select Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069577/wpf-listview-programmatically-select-item)

Comment: I couldnt adjust it to my solution

Comment: @lsi: what do you mean saying "Focused" ?

Comment: In the link provided answer described a template for list view. Look on it. It's not small amount of code to provide just in this answer.